# SQL query for customer and order- profit data

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query. I have 2 table in first table customer and 2018, 2019 order and profit data. In second table customer and 2020 0rder and profit data.

I want to write a query that will return all customer and their order and profit in a different format.

I have attached the screenshot of data and output.

[image]

Comment: What's your best guess so far? As a tip, I would recommend left joining each table onto a list of distinct customers, generated by taking the union of the customer id in both tables

Comment: not getting how to implement this

Comment: What kind of SQL database are you using? Does it support full outer join?

Comment: Is fixing your data model an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use full outer join

```
select
coalesce(t1.customer,t2.customer) as customer,
t1.order2018.t1.profit2018,t1.order2019,t1.profit2019,
t2.order2020,t2.profit2020
 from table1 as t1 full outer join table2 t2
on t1.cutomer=t2.customer
```

Comment: Thanks alot Zaynul .. It's really helped